# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract string in <script> tag email?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In a given .html page, I have a script tag like so:

```
 <script>
        atomic({
            "playlist": [{
                "id": "123456",
                "email": "ename@email.com",
                "token": "92426029ccf14bca5e495a419868af30"
            }]
            }
        }).$mount('#app');
    </script>
```

How can I use Beautiful Soup to extract the email address?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please show us your attempt to code this as well?

Comment: How to use Beautiful Soup py

Comment: You can find documentation on beautifulsoup here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/  Try to get it working and if it does not work let us know where you are stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the `<script>` tag using `soup.find('script')`, and then use the built-in `re` module to extract the email after calling `.string`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(script, "html.parser")
script_tag = soup.find("script")

print(
    re.search(r'"email": "(.*?)"', script_tag.string).group(1)
)
```

Output:

```
ename@email.com
```

Comment: You could also fish out the JSON object and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way.

- Select the `<script>` tag first and then extract it's text using `.string`. Note that `get_text()` will not work for `<script>`
- To get the internal JSON string do some string manipulations like - *Remove tabs, newlines, spaces etc., and strip off unwanted data.*
- Convert the JSON string to a JSON object using `json` module and extract the info you need.

Here is how it is done.

```
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<script>
        atomic({
            "playlist": [{
                "id": "123456",
                "email": "ename@email.com",
                "token": "92426029ccf14bca5e495a419868af30"
            }]
        
        }).$mount('#app');
    </script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('script')
x = t.string.strip()
x = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", x) #Removing the newlines, spaces and tabs from string

# Stripping off unwanted characters from string to get the internal JSON string
x = x.lstrip('atomic(') 
x = x.rstrip(').$mount(\'#app\');')

json_str = json.loads(x)

for i,v in json_str['playlist'][0].items():
    print(f"{i}: {v}")
```

```
id: 123456
email: ename@email.com
token: 92426029ccf14bca5e495a419868af30
```